# Mass edit document Id during migration

Tags: document-migration

I have a group that wants to migrate a document library from a sharepoint 2003 site to o365. Their documents are manually numbered right now, but they want to switch to using sp2013 automatic document IDs. Their documents contain references to each other based on the old numbering system.
Does anyone know a of a good method to mass edit the internal document references to reflect the new IDs that will be generated by sharepoint? Is there a way to do a find and replace across an entire document library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest migrate data to dev sp2013 farm, activate document IDs, use powershell oto connect documents based on old numbering and migrate to O365.